# How to elegantly parse a string to have exactly what you need?

Tags: java, string

I currently have a S3 bucket directory key like this:

`String dir = "s3://mybucket/workflow/science/sweet-humoor/vars";`

What I am trying to do is to get the prefix of this S3 directory, a prefix is actually without `s3:://mybucket/`, so what I want to have is `workflow/science/sweet-humoor/vars`

Now, what would be a elegant way to achieve this? I know the quickest way to do is to do a `subString(13)`, but this will break whenever the bucket name changes.

How would you handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`URIBuilder`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) class from the `org.apache.http.client.utils` package can do that.

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(dir);
String thePath = builder.getPath();
```

This automatically extracts `/workflow/science/sweet-humoor/vars` from the path. The retrieved path does not include `mybucket`, because `URIBuilder` sees the first part immediately after the protocol specifier (`s3://`) as *hostname*.

Further processing can be done through `Path p = Paths.get(thePath)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression with `replaceAll`:

```
String result = directoryKey.replaceAll("s3://[^/]+/", "");
```

The regex here is:

```
s3://[^/]+/
```

It matches the part that you want to remove, which is `s3://` followed by a bunch of non-slash characters, followed by a slash.

Answer (score 1):

It's cleanest to use the Java library functions for paths instead of handling the Strings directly. What you have is an URL, so

```
URL url = new URL(dir);
URI uri = url.toURI();
Path fullpath = Paths.get(uri);
```

Now you have a `Path` (ie the "/mybucket/workflow/science/sweet-humoor/vars" part), and you can get the subpath by

```
// start index 1 to skip the first directory element
Path subpath = fullpath.subpath(1, fullpath.getNameCount()-1);
```

You can make a `File` out of this (`subpath.toFile()`), or just get the path string by

```
subpath.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`String dir2=dir.replaceAll("s3://"+dir.split("/")[2]+"/","");`

Answer (score 0):

```
String dir = "s3://mybucket/workflow/science/sweet-humoor/vars";
dir = dir.replace("//", "").substring( dir.indexOf("/") );
System.err.println(dir);  // prints mybucket/workflow/science/sweet-humoor/vars
```

Answer (score -1):

I would split the string by "/" and get the values from third index and join it with "/". Sample code in python.

```
input_string = "s3://mybucket/workflow/science/sweet-humoor/vars"

list1 = (input_string.split("/"))
print(list1)
print("/".join(list1[3:]))
```

Output:
workflow/science/sweet-humoor/vars